# What's wrong with this Automator Workflow for YouTube-dl (AppleScript)

Tags: applescript, automator, youtube-dl

ytURL = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ

do shell script "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl -o ~/Desktop/DownloadedVideo.mp4 " + ytURL

(see photo for more info)

[Screenshot + error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8Xj6.png)

Comment: Actions don't have access to Automator variables like that.  The `input` parameter of the **Run AppleScript** action's `run` handler is the input from the workflow.

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks for the reply but I still get the "Variable not defined" error:

Comment: @user3439894 I followed your suggestions: do shell script "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl -o ~/Desktop/DownloadedVideo.mp4" & quoted form of ytURL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the **Run AppleScript** *action* use the following example:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl -o ~/Desktop/DownloadedVideo.mp4" & space & quoted form of item 1 of input
    
end run
```

---

Per CJK's comment, if you want to use a **Run Shell Script** *action* instead, then use:

- **Pass input:** *as arguments*

Replace the default *code* with just:

```
/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl -o ~/Desktop/DownloadedVideo.mp4 "$1"
```

Comment: @GianiX, since you're merely using AppleScript to execute a shell script, it would make sense for you to use a **Run Shell Script** action _instead_ of a **Run AppleScript** action.